# Why should we not use IE legacy document "edge" mode for all pages viewed with IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

In the [Microsoft documentation for Understanding legacy document modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx), it reads:

> *edge mode*... places Internet Explorer into the highest supported document mode. Edge most is most useful for regularly maintained websites that are routinely tested for interoperability between multiple browsers, including Internet Explorer. ... Starting with IE11, **edge mode is considered the preferred document mode**.

But then says...

> Because it forces all pages to be opened in standards mode, regardless of the version of Internet Explorer, **you might be tempted to use edge mode for all pages viewed with Internet Explorer. Don't do this**, as the X-UA-Compatible header is only supported starting with Internet Explorer 8.

(emphasis mine)

I don't understand what these last sentences are warning against; it seems to contradict the previous statement.

If I'm making a website that will be regularly tested and updated, and should be usable by a variety of IE versions, why would I not want to use `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" >` just because this tag is not supported by IE before version 8?

Answer (score 1):

You have *no* idea how I *wish* I could fix that...

The tl;dr answer is that, imho, you should do precisely that.

The contradiction you've identified comes because the document was written at a specific point in time and the guidance changed after the document had been first published.  Schedules and resources were such that it wasn't possible to rewrite the materials.  Instead, they were patched as best they could be, given the staffing, the workload, and the changing story.

Originally (IE8), edge mode was considered a testing mode, one unsuitable for production.  When the content from that document was first written (during the IE9 project), the guidance from the product team very clearly said to target the specific version of IE that the page was designed to support.  (To be fair, this came after much criticism regarding the differences between IE6 standards mode and IE7 standards mode.)

Later, the guidance changed to say that it was better to use the HTML5 doctype for all versions of IE, as that would (at least) enable the highest support possible (for IE6 or later).

(If you look at the related documents in the IE section of MSDN, you'll find a quiet, but consistent reference to the HTML5 doctype.)

To answer your final question, what you really want is:

- Use the HTML5 doctype for all pages, including Chrome, FF, and Edge.
- Use x-ua-compatible set to `content="ie=edge"` for those still using IE8 through IE11.  It enables the highest support for standards supported by that particular version.
- Note that this works for pages loaded through the Internet zone.  If you're loading a local file or one from an intranet, then you need to add a [MotW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) or load the page from a local web server so that it's interpreted as an Internet zone request.

Remember that IE uses [security zones](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/174360) to delineate between public web pages, local web pages, and other contexts that might change the rules you *really* want enforced for a given link.  (Knowing the zone of a page is important to really understanding why IE is interpreting it as it is.)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance